# How to add an AND filter/condition to an OR condition in Magento?

Tags: magento, filter

How can achieve the following with collection filters?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (name like '%blah%' and name like 
    '%yes%') or (description like '%blah%' and description like '%yes%');
```

Or is this a bad practice for some reason?

addFieldToFilter's applied to a collection do AND and within each you can achieve OR, but this only allows:

```
(x OR y) AND (w OR z)
```

but not

```
(x AND y) OR (w AND z)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No I don't believe you're missing anything.  I ran into a similar issue a while back and used `getSelect()->where()` to work around it.

Starting with your query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (name like '%blah%' and name like 
'%yes%') or (description like '%blah%' and description like '%yes%');
```

First, I created a collection and used the `OR` array method to get the query.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
                              array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%blah%'),
                              array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%yes%')
                              ));
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
                              array('attribute' => 'description', 'like' => '%blah%'),
                              array('attribute' => 'description', 'like' => '%yes%')
                              ));
$collection->load(true); // To dump the sql as text
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`, IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) AS `description` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description_default` ON (`at_description_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_description_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_description_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description` ON (`at_description`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_description`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_description`.`store_id` = 1) 
WHERE ((IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) LIKE '%blah%') OR (IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) LIKE '%yes%')) AND ((IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) LIKE '%blah%') OR (IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) LIKE '%yes%'))
```

You'll notice that the `WHERE` statement is almost where you described it except the `OR` and `AND` are reversed.

I copied the `WHERE` portion of the query and added an extra `getSelect()->where()` line to the collection like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

// I added these lines to ensure that the collection would load 
// the fields and do the necessary joins to pull the data
$collection->addFieldToFilter('name');          
$collection->addFieldToFilter('description');

// I'm using the same WHERE statement but I have set the ANDs and ORs
// to match your requirements

$collection->getSelect()->where(" (IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) LIKE '%blah%') AND (IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) LIKE '%yes%')) OR ((IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) LIKE '%blah%') AND (IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) LIKE '%yes%')");

$collection->load(true); // To dump the sql as text again
```

The resulting output is:

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`, IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) AS `description` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description_default` ON (`at_description_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_description_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_description_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description` ON (`at_description`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_description`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_description`.`store_id` = 1) 
WHERE (IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) = '') AND (IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) = '') AND ( (IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) LIKE '%blah%') AND (IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) LIKE '%yes%')) OR ((IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) LIKE '%blah%') AND (IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) LIKE '%yes%'))
```

The `where()` in the `getSelect()` could be shortened to:

```
(`name` like '%blah%' and `name` like '%yes%') or (`description` like '%blah%' and `description` like '%yes%');
```

Any other Magento people out there please feel free to correct me if I'm too far off-base with this or if you know of a way to accomplish the same goal without using this method.

hth!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I had hoped there would be a Magento method that allowed us, for consistency sake, to avoid writing SQL, but that is a functional solution.